# Using Private object to access enum property

Tags: c#, properties, enums

I am using Private object to unit test a class. I want to access the value of Browser which is a enum and has a list of different Browsers. I keep getting "the operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type".I am using something like:

```
        Browser browser = Browser.Chrome;
        PrivateObject pvtObject = new PrivateObject(ClassName);
        Browser browserProperty = pvtObject.GetFieldOrProperty("Browser") as Browser;
```

UPDATE
When I use :

```
var browserProperty = pvtObject.GetFieldOrProperty("Browser");
```

It works fine, but I need to know why..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you're getting tells you what your issue is.  The `as` operator is used to perform certain types of conversions between reference types or nullable types.  Your Browser enum is a non-nullable value type, and therefore cannot be used with the `as` keyword.

The following works because you are defining your `browserProperty` variable using the implicit type `var`.  At compile time, the `browserProperty` variable is strongly typed as an `object` due to the return type of the `GetFieldOrProperty` method.  The following two lines are equivalent:

```
var browserProperty = pvtObject.GetFieldOrProperty("Browser");
object browserProperty = pvtObject.GetFieldOrProperty("Browser");
```

Using the following line works because you are explicitly casting the return type (an object) to an enum.

```
Browser browserTypeProperty = (Browser)pvt_Object.GetFieldOrProperty("Browser");
```

If you *really* want to use the `as` keyword, the right-hand side of the `as` operation must use a nullable version of your enum:

```
Browser? browserProperty = pvtObject.GetFieldOrProperty("Browser") as Browser?;
```

Comment: Really?  I am waiting for you getting some rep points to downvote :)

Comment: @LB:  Expanded my answer to better explain why the different lines he was using work.  Is that a better answer?

Comment: @Eugene I understood your answer and even Upvoted your answer but my reputation is a bit low to vote :P By the way thanks I totally got your point. :)